# Генерация числового массива

Tags: jquery, массивы

Нужен длинный массив в 100 "ячеек", с "шагом" `+5` и начинаться должен не с нуля.
Типо так: `arr = ['5','10','15',...];`

Написать такой в ручную - можно, но это займёт время.
Вопрос, как "красиво" и компактно генерировать такой массив?

Comment: используя цикл `for`. При чем здесь jQuery?

Comment: @Igor, использую эту библиотеку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var arr = array(100)
for(var int i=1; i<=100; i++) arr[i-1] = i*5;`

Answer (score 2):

Используйте функцию  _.range() из lodash.js

`_.range(5, 500, 5);`

Вернёт:

`=> [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, ...]`